# apply condition on json file and fetch the value on that key value exists in linux

Tags: arrays, json, shell, jq

I have the `packages.json` file which contains the docker image details, looks like:

```
  "dependencies": [
{
  "name": "powershell-core",
  "type": "zip",
  "path": "Dependencies",
  "filename": "PowerShell-Core-6.2.3-win-x64.msi"
},
{
"name": "redis",
"type": "docker-image",
"path": "redis:6.0.10-alpine3.12",
"filename": ""
},
{
  "name": "keycloak",
  "type": "docker-image",
  "path": "jboss/keycloak:12.0.1",
  "filename": ""
},
]
```

The JSON data is semi-structured and all is not the same. Here I am trying to fetch specific data like `"path"` with condition like if its a `"type": "docker-image"` under `"dependencies"` then fetch it.

I have tried something like:

```
$ jq '.dependencies[2].path' packages.json
```

output:

```
"redis:6.0.10-alpine3.12"
```

So how to fetch all the `"path"` having `"type"` as `"docker-image"` under `"dependencies"` from the **packages.json** file and keep it in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select` to filter an array:

```
jq -r '.dependencies[] | select(.type == "docker-image").path' packages.json
```

The `-r` removes the double quotes around the paths.

Use redirection to save the output to a file:

```
... > output
```

Comment: Yes its working fine, but I am running this command in a `do-while` loop in linux, so every time it hits this command it should only take one `"path"` and store it a variable untill the condition checks for the `"type":docker-image`. Is it possible to achieve.

Comment: Create a new question to ask a new question. You can link to the old one for context.

Comment: I have created a new one.